# Ruby gem to run sql commands

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I want to run sql commands directly in my rails application. Is there any gem to do this?

For example:

I want to delete a user , who is having id 2 using below sql command

```
 delete from users where id=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can do that by using [query_exec](https://rubygems.org/gems/query_exec)

Answer (score 4):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("delete from users where id=2")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run SQL from your browser try https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db